# Click on element to filter column in javascript (datatables)

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using javascript DataTables to display data, and would like to modify filters by clicking on data items as well as the standard menus.  For example, I have a table like this (obviously not including the javascript functions necessary to filter):

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>number</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Bob</td>
            <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Sue</td>
            <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Sue</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Bob</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Frank</td>
            <td>5</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

If the viewer clicks on 'Bob', I want the filter to be updated to only display rows containing 'Bob'.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ColumnFilterWidgets](http://www.datatables.net/extras/thirdparty/ColumnFilterWidgets/DataTables/extras/ColumnFilterWidgets/) or [ColumnFilter](http://jquery-datatables-column-filter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/index.html).

There are examples, snippets and docs in those pages. I hope it helps.